# ASP.Net Core APP and SQL on Azure - Problem with converting numbers - Code works local?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an APP which I tested local on my PC (Germany), after everything worked well I published it to AZURE as APP, SQL DB is in Azure too.

Now I have following problem:

Local PC with German Localization I can type "2,16" in a field and the database stored it right as 2.16.

After I publish the APP to Azure and I type "2,16" in a field, the database stored the value 216 (without comma or dot)...

Is there any possibility e.g in Startup.cs if the APP runs local or in Azure ?

I can do some code like this:

```
var webseite = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_SITE_NAME");
```

and then check if website runs in AZURE, but this is ugly, it would be better if I can setup the Localisation once in startup.cs or anywhere else - hope someone have an idea to fix this without change code in every situation where I run to this problem... ?

Thanks for help
Peter

Edit: the possible duplicate remark is not that what i am looking for - nothing from the given thread helps ? It is still that he use 216 instead of 2,16.
When i type 2.16 he use correct value for updating the Database with EF Core.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force locale with Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519068/force-locale-with-asp-net-core)

Comment: see Edit in Post - not what i`m looking for

Comment: I think the referenced link is indeed what you are looking for. the comma is not recognized in Azure as you expect because the local in Azure is English - as opposed to your German setting on your dev machine

Comment: Can you please share your code where you transport 2,16 from a form to a number?

Answer (score 0):

This is what works as expected now with local
and on AZURE too in Startup.cs:

```
 `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";
```

}`

thanks for the hint !